# Running Program from Call Doesn't Seg Fault

Tags: subprocess, fault

My program `writenotes` keeps seg faulting when I try to write a note that is too long.

```
./writenotes lolololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololo
[ * ] Writing notes
Segmentation fault
```

Anyways, I was trying to write a python script that calls the program and curiously enough, calling it from a python script doesn't bring a seg fault, which I thought was rather peculiar.

Heres this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call

call(["./writenotes", "lolololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololo"])
```

Which returns

```
[ * ] Writing notes
```

Is this because of parent processing or something like such?  How would calling a program through subprocess save a program from a segfault though?  Are there other ways to call programs from a script that suffer seg faults?

As a note, the writenotes program was written in C.  The other script is python.

Comment: We need to see your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll almost certainly find your C program *is* crashing but that Python is hiding that from you. Try instead with:

```
print call(["./writenotes", "lolololol..."])
```

and see what you get as a return value.

---

For example, *this* program tries to modify a string literal and, when run normally dumps core:

```
int main (void) {
    *"xyzzy" = 'X';
    return 0;
}
```

However, when run from the following script:

```
from subprocess import call
print call(["./testprog"])
```

I get the output `-11`, indicating that signal `11` (usually `SIGSEGV`) was raised, as per the documentation discussing `Popen.returncode` which `subprocess.call()` uses under the covers:

> A negative value `-N` indicates that the child was terminated by signal `N` (Unix only).

---

An alternative to checking the return code is to import `check_call` and `CalledProcessError` instead of `call` and then use that function. It will raise an exception if the return code is non-zero.

That's probably not so important if you're only calling one executable (just get the return value in that case) but, if you're doing a lot in sequence, catching an exception from the entire group may be more readable.

Changing the C program to only crash when the first argument is `3`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf ("hello there %s\n", argv[1]);
        if (strcmp (argv[1], "3") == 0)
            *"xyzzy" = 'X';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the script to call it with several different arguments:

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError
try:
    check_call(["./testprog", "0"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "1"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "2"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "3"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "4"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "5"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "6"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "7"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "8"])
    check_call(["./testprog", "9"])
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.cmd, "failed with", e.returncode
else:
    print "Everything went well"
```

shows that in action:

```
hello there 0
hello there 1
hello there 2
hello there 3
['./testprog', '3'] failed with -11
```